# Compile current .cpp file VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

What is the hot-key or where can I go to compile my current file in VS2008 C++? Thx.

Comment: Do you compile your project or file ? Compiling a file is surely new to me. Project is F7, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-F7 - current **file**

F7 - **project**

Comment: Thank you, any idea how to switch hotkeys around?

Comment: Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard   There you can switch hotkeys